# Save data from Dialog Box to String in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, string, debugging, textview

Can Anyone tell me how to save data of Dialog Box into String. I am Created one QR Code Scanning App in which I want store data which scanned by QR code. I am tried following code but showing an error when trying to to get data from dialog box to string. Error on this Line **String  user_data = data.getText().toString();** at ***getText()***. Please Tell me how resolve this error.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
   IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
   if (result!=null && result.getContents()!=null){

       new AlertDialog.Builder(all_Entries.this)
               .setTitle("Customer Information")
               .setMessage(result.getContents())
               //Save Button
               .setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        addDataToDatabase();
                   }
                   private void addDataToDatabase() {


                       String  user_data = data.getText().toString();
                       // Here getText() Function is not working Showing an Error : **Cannot resolve method 'getText' in 'Intent'**


                       UserData userData = new UserData(user_data);
                       repository = new MyRepository(MyDatabase.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).myDao());
                       repository.addUser(userData);
                       Toast.makeText(all_Entries.this, "Data is Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   }
               })

               //Save Button End

               .setNegativeButton("Cancle", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
               dialog.dismiss();
           }
       }).create().show();
   }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`@Nullable Intent data` data is not a `EditText` or `TextView` it's an `Intent` so I think `data.toString()` will work.